Meteor Accounts.createUser - Meteor crashes when user exists
I'm new to Meteor and trying to figure out, how Account.createUser() works when the user is in the database already and meteor checks for duplicate entries.
I've created a Meteor method:
'test.createUser'(user) {
try {
  Accounts.createUser(
    {
      username: user.username,
      email: user.emails[0].address,
      profile: user.profile,
    },
  );
} catch (exception) {
  console.log('Error creating user:', exception);
  throw exception;
}

},
Which I call on the client side:
createUser() {
  Meteor.call(
    "test.createUser",
    {
      username: "myuser",
      emails: [{ address: "myuser@example.com", verified: true }],
      profile: {
        profile: "userProfile",
        name: "New User",
        path: null,
      },
    },
    (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      }
    }
  );
},

If the user did not exist in mongo and test.createUser is called the 1st time, the user is created. On subsequent calls, I'd expect that the catch-block of test.createUser runs, as the username and email are in use already.
However, this does not happen. Instead, Meteor crashes with the error displayed on the console:

W20241231-09:01:11.046(1)? (STDERR) meteor://app/packages/accounts-base.js:685
W20241231-09:01:11.046(1)? (STDERR)           const error = new Meteor.Error(errorCode, isErrorAmbiguous ? 'Something went wrong. Please check your credentials.' : msg);
W20241231-09:01:11.046(1)? (STDERR)                         ^
W20241231-09:01:11.067(1)? (STDERR) errorClass [Error]: Something went wrong. Please check your credentials. [403]
W20241231-09:01:11.067(1)? (STDERR)     at AccountsServer._handleError (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1523:19)
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR)     at AccountsServer._checkForCaseInsensitiveDuplicates (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1491:14)
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR)     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR)     at AccountsServer._createUserCheckingDuplicates (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1504:5)
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR)     at AccountsServer.createUser (packages/accounts-password/password_server.js:996:12) {
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR)   isClientSafe: true,
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR)   error: 403,
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR)   reason: 'Something went wrong. Please check your credentials.',
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR)   details: undefined,
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR)   errorType: 'Meteor.Error'
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR) }
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR)
W20241231-09:01:11.068(1)? (STDERR) Node.js v22.11.0

Catching the exception and re-throw it does not work.
I've also tried to call Accunts.createUser on the client side:
createUser2() {
  const user = {
      username: "myuser",
      emails: [{ address: "myuser@example.com", verified: true }],
      password: "secret",
      profile: {
        profile: "userProfile",
        name: "New User",
        path: null,
      },
    },
  };
  try {
    Accounts.createUser(
      {
        username: user.username,
        email: user.emails[0].address,
        password: user.password,
        profile: user.profile,
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log("we got an error:", err);
      }
    );
  } catch (exception) {
    console.log("Error creating user:", exception);
    throw exception;
  }
},

},

we got an error:
{
"isClientSafe": true,
"error": 403,
"reason": "Something went wrong. Please check your credentials.",
"message": "Something went wrong. Please check your credentials. [403]",
"errorType": "Meteor.Error"
}

In client mode, the callback containing the error runs.
But how can I catch it when using the Meteor method and avoid crashing Meteor?
